# GetWindowRect returns a Rect with 0 on every property when called with MainWindowHandle from a process that is firefox

Tags: c#, firefox, rect, user32

I need to do a screenshot from firefox with a Winforms Application and doing so using the GetWindowRect and creating a Bitmap based on the Rect from there does not work. The Rect has 0 Bottom, 0 Top, 0 Left and 0 Right. For other Tasks like the explorer works fine.

I first thought that firefox has some processes that are not the main window so I started some new and tried grabbing some other processes that contain the name firefox from my array with process, but the error is everytime the same.

```
 Bitmap screenshot = CaptureApplication("firefox");

 public Bitmap CaptureApplication(string procName)
    {

        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
  //getting the first process with the name firefox
        var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)[0]; 
//Get a rect in the size of the firefox process
        var rect = new User32.Rect();
        User32.GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);
            return rect;
        });
//Make screenshot based on the size of the rect (ante)
       var t2= t.ContinueWith((ante) =>
        {
            var rect = ante.Result;

        int width = rect.right - rect.left; //right and left are 0
        int height = rect.bottom - rect.top; //bottom and top are 0
        //here is the error
        var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height,   PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb); //cant create a Bitmap with 0,0 as parameter
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(rect.left, rect.top, 0, 0, new Size(width, height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            return bmp;
        });
        return t2.Result;
    }
 public class User32
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Rect
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);
}
```

I just want a screenshot of firefox but the program wont run as long as it returns 0 for every property of the rect.

Comment: Why `var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)[0];`? Nobody said that the first process you get is the Windowed one. Try with `var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName).Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero).FirstOrDefault();`. Also, note that `GetWindowRect()` is not DPIAware.

Comment: The `graphics` object must be disposed of. I don't get why you're using  `Task.Run().ContinueWith()` here.